# Kotlin - Readln() gets only first word in string

Tags: kotlin, readline

I'm making a first project "Flashcards" for Kotlin course and faced with unexpected program behavior. Function "readln()" gets only first word in sting (separetad by space " "). What is a problem, what do you think?
Note: fun "reading" needed and for now I can realize it in this way only. Regular "readln()" have same problem.
Code below.

```
import java.util.*

var logText: String = ""
fun println(text: String = "") {
    kotlin.io.println(text)
    logText += text + "\n"
}
fun reading(): String {
    val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val text = scan.next()
    logText += text + "\n"
    return text
}

fun adding(addCard: MutableMap<String, String>): MutableMap<String, String> {
    val definition: String
    println("The card:")
    val card: String = reading()
    if (card in addCard.keys) {
        println("The card \"$card\" already exists.")
        return addCard
    } else {
        println("The definition of the card:")
        definition = reading()
        if (definition in addCard.values) {
            println("The definition \"$definition\" already exists.")
            return addCard
        }
    }
    addCard[card] = definition
    println("The pair (\"${card}\":\"${definition}\") has been added.")
    return addCard
}

fun main() {
    val actionList = mutableListOf("add", "exit")
    var action = ""
    val cards = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
    while (action != "exit") {
        println("Input the action (add, remove, exit):")
        action = reading()
        if (action !in actionList) {
            println("Wrong action!")
            continue
        } else {
            when (action) {
                "add" -> cards.putAll(adding(cards))
                /* "remove" -> println("Not supported.")
                "import" -> println("Not supported.")
                "export" -> println("Not supported.")
                "ask" -> println("Not supported.")
                "log" -> println("Not supported.")
                "hardest card" -> println("Not supported.")
                "reset stats" -> println("Not supported.") */
            }
        }
    }
    println("Bye bye!")
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that didn't work, since that's what you're asking about? There's no way to tell what you did wrong without seeing what you did.

Comment: `readln()` and `readLine()` functions are for getting a line. and also with scanner you can use `scanner.nextLine()` function. for me these functions work as expected. so please post the code that doesn't work so we can check it.

Comment: problem with the above code is that you should use `scan.nextLine()` instead of `scan.next()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `readln()` in your code, you're using a `Scanner` with the `next()` function and no delimiter set. So by default, that just splits on words:

```
import java.util.Scanner

fun main() {
    val input = "here are some words"
    val scanner = Scanner(input)
    while(scanner.hasNext()) {
        println(scanner.next())
    }
}
```

```
here
are
some
words
```

If you use `scanner.nextLine()` then it'll read the whole line as a token, and that's basically the behaviour of `readln()` as well. If `readln()` is giving you individual words, you'll have to post the code that's doing that, because it'll be something else going on

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! The solution is so obvious, ha ha :)